# C# - WPF Entity Framework - Remove Selected Record from Database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

In my C# / WPF application, I have a `ListView` control, which I populate as follows:

```
private void Load()
{
    DbSet<recordHistory> recordHistory = _db.recordHistories;

    var query = from cbHistory in recordHistory
                orderby cbHistory.id descending
                select new { cbHistory.id, cbHistory.Content, cbHistory.Size, cbHistory.DateAdded };
    crRecordHistoryList.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
}
```

The above works as expected. My `ListView` control is populated with all the saved records from a SQL database.

When I start debugging the application, it executes as expected. However, when I select one of the `ListView` items (regardless of which item I select) and click on the `Remove` button, **only the first record** gets removed from the database and the ListView control.

Intended behavior is for the **selected** record to be removed from the database & the listview control...

My `Remove` method

```
private void Button_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var record in _db.recordHistories.Local.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Removing Record Id:" + record.id);
        _db.recordHistories.Remove(record);
    }

    _db.SaveChanges();

    this.crRecordHistoryList.Items.Refresh();
    this.Load();
}
```

Furthermore, all subsequent item selection and clicking on the remove button result in nothing being removed from database/listview control)

I have also tried the following (just to get the ID), within the `Remove` method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Removing Record Id:" + (crRecordHistoryList.SelectedItem as recordHistory).id);
```

in which case, I get:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

My `recordHistory` class (auto generated)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class recordHistory
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**: I have figured out **why** it only removes the first record and then nothing else happens (no matter which item is selected)... it is because instead of getting the record from `Local` (in my `foreach` statement), I should simply have the following --- which was my initial attempt, trying to get the ID outputted to `Console`:

```
private void Button_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    recordHistory testRecord = new recordHistory();
    testRecord.id = (recordHistory)crRecordHistoryList.SelectedItem;
    _db.recordHistories.Attach(testRecord);
    _db.recordHistories.Remove(testRecord);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    this.crRecordHistoryList.Items.Refresh();
    this.Load();
}
```

However, the following line

```
testRecord.id = (recordHistory)crRecordHistoryList.SelectedItem;
```

is throwing an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'recordHistory' to 'int'

By the way: the above would work perfectly, if I replace the 2nd line with: `testRecord.id = 85;` for example.

As such, I have tried changing the aforementioned line to the following, to no avail:

```
testRecord.id = System.Convert.ToInt32(crRecordHistoryList.SelectedItem);
```

Any ideas how I can remove the selected record?

Comment: `crRecordHistoryList.SelectedItem` is an anonymous type (`object`--mouse over your `query` variable and you'll see the static type of the enumerable). You got the can't convert `recordHistory` to `int` because you tried casting the object to `recordHistory` and then tried assigning *that* to `id` which is an `int`. What about `select new recordHistory {...}` in your linq statement or at least to a view model class instead of the anonymous type. Then you'll be able to access the properties strongly typed.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks! Your comment pointed me in the direction of further research and the outcome is a solved problem (I've posted my solution), along with learning more on the way --- I'd absolutely welcome a correct (or, just "better") approach, if there is one (being a C#/WPF newbie, I am sure there is :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to @pinkfloydx33 for pointing me in the right direction. Per his comment, I ventured onto further-research-rabbit-hole which eventually led to me creating a DTO class and modified my `Load` and `Remove` methods as follows--

`Load` method

```
private void Load()
{
    List<HistoryRecordsDTO> records = (from record in _db.recordHistories
                                        orderby record.id descending
                                        select new HistoryRecordsDTO
                                        {
                                            id = record.id,
                                            Content = record.Content,
                                            Size = record.Size,
                                            DateAdded = record.DateAdded
                                        }).ToList();
    crRecordHistoryList.ItemsSource = records;
}
```

`Remove` method

```
private void Button_Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    recordHistory record = new recordHistory();
    record.id = (crRecordHistoryList.SelectedItem as HistoryRecordsDTO).id;
    _db.recordHistories.Attach(record);
    _db.recordHistories.Remove(record);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    this.crRecordHistoryList.Items.Refresh();
    this.Load();
}
```

And, my `DTO` class - `HistoryRecordsDTO`

```
public class HistoryRecordsDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

**Doing the above solved my problem of removing a selected `ListView` item.**

As being a C#/WPF newbie, I am certain that there are much nicer/optimal/better in general ways to do this... I look forward to other answers and learn from it.